Choropleth map not rendering in shiny app
I am having trouble getting a shiny app to render a plotly map. The map does not display. i use this link for reference: https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/
I found similar queston here but the solution is nor working for me:
Plot.ly map not rendering in shiny app.
I spent more than 12 hours on this question but still cannot figure it out. Please help me! I would deeply appreciate!

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


library(plotly)

library(tidyr)



library(scales)

extended_data <- data.frame(
  Date = c("8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", 
           "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/14/24", "8/14/24"),
  Type = c("D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F"),
  state = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
            "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"),
  value = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
            0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  party = c("Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", 
            "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic"),
  Democratic = rep(0.50326087, 20), # Simplifying for the example
  StateFull = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", 
                "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland"),
  Percent_byStateParty = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  abb = c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
          "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"),
  party2 = c("Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic",
             "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic")
)






# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  #theme = bslib::bs_theme(primary = "orange"),
  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  
             
             tabPanel("US Map", icon = icon("map-marker"),
                      titlePanel("Map2"),
                      
                      # Organize elements horizontally using fluidRow and column
                      fluidRow(
                        column(4, 
                               fileInput("file2", "Choose your CSV File", accept = ".csv")
                        ),
                        column(4,
                               radioButtons("voicechoice", "Choice of Voice", 
                                            choices = c("D", "F", "B", "M"), 
                                            selected = "D"),
                               bsTooltip(id = "voicechoice", 
                                         title = "Select type")
                        ),
                        
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          column(4,
                                 dateInput("Date_map", "Date:", value = "2024-08-13"),
                                 
                                 pickerInput(inputId = "USMap_state",
                                             label = "Select States (Max 4)",
                                             choices = state.name,  # Make sure averaged_data$Type is available
                                             multiple = TRUE,
                                             options = list(maxItems = 4, placeholder = 'Enter state name',
                                                            onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))
                                 ))  # Close column
                          
                        ),
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          column(12,
                                 plotOutput(outputId = "Plot_Map")
                          )
                        ),
                       
                      )),  # 
             
             
)



#View(averaged_data)
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  
  ##----------
  USA_map <- reactive({
    req(input$voicechoice)
    req(input$Date_map)
    filter(extended_data, Type %in% input$voicechoice) %>%
      filter(Date %in% input$Date_map)%>%
      mutate(new_variable = runif(n(), min = 0, max = 50))%>%
      mutate(party_numeric= ifelse(party2 == "Republican", 1, 0))%>%
      mutate(hover = paste(state, '<br>', 
                           "State:", state, "<br>",
                           "Date:", Date, "<br>",
                           "Type:", Type, "<br>",
                           " Party:", party2))
  })
  
  output$Plot_Map <- renderPlotly ({
    input$voicechoice
    input$Date_map
   
    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = 'usa',
      projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB('white')
    )
    
    fig <- plot_geo(USA_map(), locationmode = 'USA-states')
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
      z = ~party_numeric, text = ~hover, locations = ~state
    )
    fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Map")
    fig <- fig %>% layout(
      title = 'Map)',
      geo = g
    )
    
    fig
  })  
  
 
  observe({
    data <- USA_map()
    print(data, n = 8, width = Inf)  # Look at this output in your R console or log
  })
  
  
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


I want the map is rendering for my shiny app. It currently does not show anything. Nothing displayed.

You must replace plotOutput by plotlyOutput in your UI part. And replace all "24" in your date column by "2024", then convert to Date format with extended_data$Date = as.Date(extended_data$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

Here is your corrected code:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)

extended_data <- data.frame(
  Date = c(
    "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24",
    "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/13/24", "8/14/24", "8/14/24"
  ),
  Type = c("D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F", "D", "B", "M", "F"),
  state = c(
    "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
    "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"
  ),
  value = c(
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
  ),
  party = c(
    "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic",
    "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Democratic"
  ),
  Democratic = rep(0.50326087, 20), # Simplifying for the example
  StateFull = c(
    "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
    "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland"
  ),
  Percent_byStateParty = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
  ),
  abb = c(
    "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA",
    "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD"
  ),
  party2 = c(
    "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic",
    "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic", "Democratic"
  )
)






# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # theme = bslib::bs_theme(primary = "orange"),
  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  tabPanel("US Map",
    icon = icon("map-marker"),
    titlePanel("Map2"),

    # Organize elements horizontally using fluidRow and column
    fluidRow(
      column(
        4,
        fileInput("file2", "Choose your CSV File", accept = ".csv")
      ),
      column(
        4,
        radioButtons("voicechoice", "Choice of Voice",
          choices = c("D", "F", "B", "M"),
          selected = "D"
        ),
        bsTooltip(
          id = "voicechoice",
          title = "Select type"
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          4,
          dateInput("Date_map", "Date:", value = "2024-08-13"),
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "USMap_state",
            label = "Select States (Max 4)",
            choices = state.name, # Make sure averaged_data$Type is available
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(
              maxItems = 4, placeholder = "Enter state name",
              onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
            )
          )
        ) # Close column
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          12,
          plotlyOutput(outputId = "Plot_Map")
        )
      ),
    )
  ), #
)



# View(averaged_data)
server <- function(input, output) {
  ## ----------
  USA_map <- reactive({
    req(input$voicechoice)
    req(input$Date_map)
    filter(extended_data, Type %in% input$voicechoice) %>%
      filter(Date %in% input$Date_map) %>%
      mutate(new_variable = runif(n(), min = 0, max = 50)) %>%
      mutate(party_numeric = ifelse(party2 == "Republican", 1, 0)) %>%
      mutate(hover = paste(
        state, "<br>",
        "State:", state, "<br>",
        "Date:", Date, "<br>",
        "Type:", Type, "<br>",
        " Party:", party2
      ))
  })

  output$Plot_Map <- renderPlotly({
    input$voicechoice
    input$Date_map

    # specify some map projection/options
    g <- list(
      scope = "usa",
      projection = list(type = "albers usa"),
      showlakes = TRUE,
      lakecolor = toRGB("white")
    )

    fig <- plot_geo(USA_map(), locationmode = "USA-states")
    fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
      z = ~party_numeric, text = ~hover, locations = ~state
    )
    fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Map")
    fig <- fig %>% layout(
      title = "Map)",
      geo = g
    )

    fig
  })


  observe({
    data <- USA_map()
    print(data, n = 8, width = Inf) # Look at this output in your R console or log
  })
}



# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

First of all, you called a couple of functions from packages that were not loaded. Specifically the bsTooltip() function from the shinyBS package, and the pickerInput() function from shinyWidgets package. The packages have been loaded in the above script.
Secondly, I changed plotOutput() in your UI to plotlyOutput() since it is a plotly visualization. That was the reason why your map was not rendering.


Thank you so much! ! That's the issue. What a silly mistake that I made for the last 18 hours...

@Snow Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read What should I do when someone answers my question?. TLDR; the answer above solved your issue so you can mark it as accepted. Also, generally if you find an answer or a question useful you can upvote it (if you you have earn the privilege to do so).
